# how can i exclude fields in typo3 search form?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

i have a website in typo3 and i want to add a search form (typo3's search form). how can i customize the search? i want to search only in page's bodytext. I want to exlude fields such as meta title, keywords etc.
thank you! I found this on a website, but I don't know where to modify

```
$TCA['tx_yourext_table'] = array(
    'ctrl' => array(
        'title' => 'Title of your table',
        'label' => 'title',
        'tstamp' => 'tstamp',
        'crdate' => 'crdate',
         // etc...
        'searchFields' => 'title, other_field, yet_other_field',
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it in template setup using this:

```
tt_content.search.20.allowedCols = tt_content.bodytext
tt_content.search.30.dataArray.value = tt_content.bodytext
```

In my case, 20 is the SEARCHRESULT object, 30 is the FORM object; modify them as necessary.

The default values are something like this, just for reference:

```
pages.title-subtitle-keywords-description : tt_content.header-bodytext-imagecaption
```